# ¿Cómo devolver solo columnas diferentes entre dos registros?

Tags: sql-server

Tengo dos tablas con la misma estructura pero tengo que comparar sus contenidos para encontrar diferencias. Los registros con diferencias consigo devolverlos correctamente pero me gustaría saber si se puede llegar a devolver las columnas que tienen valor diferente.

```
declare @tabla_original table (campo1 int, campo2 varchar(15), campo3 varchar(15))
insert into @tabla_original values (1, 'uno','A')
insert into @tabla_original values (2, 'dos','B')
insert into @tabla_original values (3, 'tres','C')
insert into @tabla_original values (4, 'cuatro','D')

declare @tabla_final table (campo1 int, campo2 varchar(15), campo3 varchar(15))
insert into @tabla_final values (3, 'tres','C')
insert into @tabla_final values (2, 'dos','B')
insert into @tabla_final values (1, 'uno','C')
insert into @tabla_final values (44, 'cuatro','D')

select * from @tabla_final
except
select * from @tabla_original
```

En esta prueba los registros 1 y 4 son diferentes. El 4 en la tabla_final no existe pero el 1 tiene una diferencia en el campo3. Lo que me gustaría es que me devolviera que el campo3 es el que tiene la diferencia.

Comment: Se podría, pero tienes que tomar al menos un campo como _pivote_ para comparar. ¿puedes hacerlo? ¿Cuál sería ese campo?

Answer (score 1):

Prueba de esta manera tu solución

```
select * FROM 
(select * from @tabla_final 
except 
select * from @tabla_original ) as primera 

union 

select * FROM 
(select * from @tabla_original 
except 
select * from @tabla_final ) as segunda
```